# How to reference the record in the detail portion of the VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'll start with I'm not even sure I'm going about this in the correct manner.

The idea is that when the user clicks on the Tab, they are presented with the Details & related list of the latest version of this object (it is a bookings forecast based on a fiscal week).

So I've got a controller and a visualforce page. Here is the controller (I'm just using one record Owner.Id for now).

```
public with sharing class BookingsTabController {
Bookings_Forecast__c[] bookingsForecasts;
Id BookingForecastId; 
Id UserId;
public String BookingForecastName {get; set;}

  public BookingsTabController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    try
    {
        //String Id = UserInfo.getUserId() ;

        String Id = '005500000011TP6AAM';
        Bookings_Forecast__c[] FiscalWeek = [Select Fiscal_Week__c From Bookings_Forecast__c ORDER BY Fiscal_Week__c DESC LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('\n\n********************** Fiscal week: ' + FiscalWeek[0].Fiscal_Week__c + '\n');
        bookingsForecasts = [Select Id,Name,Fiscal_Week__c from Bookings_Forecast__c WHERE Owner.Id = :Id AND Fiscal_Week__c =:FiscalWeek[0].Fiscal_Week__c];               

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Request can not be completed.'));

    }

}
public Bookings_Forecast__c[] getBookingsForecasts() {
        return bookingsForecasts;
  }

  public PageReference save() {
        update bookingsForecasts;
        return null;
  }

  public PageReference cancel() {
        return null;
  }
```

}

And here is the VisualForce page (I used Layout Page to generate it based on the standard and then plug the controller into it):

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Bookings_Forecast__c" Extensions="BookingsTabController">
```

```
        <!-- **********   [Record Type : Master ]   **********  -->
        <apex:outputpanel >
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="false" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.Name}"/>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Owner"/>
                        <apex:outputpanel >
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.OwnerId}"/>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Fcst_HW_Optical__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Est_Bkgs_HW_Optical__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Fcst_HW_Wireless__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Est_Bkgs_HW_Wireless__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Fcst_SVCS__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Est_Bkgs_SVCS__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Fcst_SW__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Est_Bkgs_SW__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Fcst_Total__c}"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.FY_Est_Bkgs_Total__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:pageblocksection title="System Information" showheader="false" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Created By"/>
                    <apex:outputpanel >
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.CreatedById}"/>&nbsp;, 
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.CreatedDate}"/>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Last Modified By"/>
                    <apex:outputpanel >
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.LastModifiedById}"/>&nbsp;, 
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c.LastModifiedDate}"/>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>

<!-- **********   [Related Lists for Record Type : Master ]   **********  -->
<apex:outputpanel >
    <apex:relatedlist list="Bookings_Forecast_Line_Item__r" title="Bookings Forecast Line Item"/>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

I know when you do a repeating list you can use something like:

```
<apex:repeat var="fcst" value="{!bookingsforecasts}"...
```

But how would you do that for the detail portion?

I'm sure it is pretty simple but it has been awhile since I've done some VF work.

thanks!

lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any of this to apply, you need to "bulkify" your controller. Your query needs to return a list. Once you do that you can do a repeat by assigning a variable to `!Bookings_Forecast__c`. E.G. `<apex:repeat var="fcst" value="{!Bookings_Forecast__c}">`

You can then use that repeat to display each value for the variables in the list of records returned from your query using lines like below:

```
<apex:outputfield value="{!fcst.FY_Fcst_HW_Optical__c}"/>
.....
.....
</repeat> // locate this where you want the repeat loop to stop
```

Note that it's *much* easier to write bulk code up front than to try and bulkify it later.

Comment: I was beginning to wonder if that was the only way to do it. Just Wrap the entire thing in a repeat loop even though there is only record returned and it will be a 2 column detail area. I'll give that a try!

Comment: It Worked. Not the most elegant solution but it does work.